# PaintCode: Circle Maintains A/R?

Tags: objective-c, paintcode

In Paintcode 2, I have a circle inside a frame inside a canvas.

The constraints on the circle are set like this:

[image]

To get the circle to size up and not become an ellipse, I have to

1. Know the expected aspect ratio
2. Code it in Objective-C myself

**Is there any way around this type of code?**

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if (rect.size.width > rect.size.height) {
        rect.origin.x = (rect.size.width - rect.size.height) * .5f;
        rect.size.width = rect.size.height;
    } else {
        rect.origin.y = (rect.size.height - rect.size.width) * .5f;
        rect.size.height = rect.size.width;
    }
    NSLog(@"Frame=%@", NSStringFromCGRect(rect));
    [CircleDraw drawCircleWithFrame:rect];
}
```

Comment: why are you changing the origin of the given rect? and are you creating the object by code or interfaceBuilder?

Comment: this is about paintcode: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/

Comment: yes i know i use this app in some of my apps. i mean where do you create the circle?

Comment: This is all done inside paintcode, but the uiview changes size dynamically

Comment: I answered below, too... thank you!

Comment: ohh didn't see that..cool :)

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a canvas, `150x120`
2. Create an ellipse, `10, 10, 100, 100`
3. Create a new variable called `frame`, type rectangle: `10, 10, 150, 100`
4. Create a new expression called smallestSide: `min(frame.height, frame.width)`
5. Make an expression called `position` (below)
6. Drag `smallestSide` to both height and width of the ellipse
7. Drag the `position` to the position of the ellipse

---

**position (Expression)**

```
 makePoint(
    frame.x+(frame.width-smallestSide)*0.5,
    frame.y+(frame.height-smallestSide)*0.5
)
```

---

**output**

```
- (void)drawCanvas1WithFrame: (CGRect)frame
{

    //// Variable Declarations
    CGFloat smallestSide = MIN(frame.size.height, frame.size.width);
    CGPoint position = CGPointMake(frame.origin.x + (frame.size.width - smallestSide) * 0.5, frame.origin.y + (frame.size.height - smallestSide) * 0.5);

    //// Oval Drawing
    UIBezierPath* ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: CGRectMake(position.x, position.y, smallestSide, smallestSide)];
    [UIColor.grayColor setFill];
    [ovalPath fill];
}
```

**NOTE:** I had the help of Matt Dunik at PaintCode to figure this out, but the solution is actually very straightforward.

Comment: I'm doing this slightly differently now, by applying it all to a frame that encloses the ellipse (and other shapes)